# Interactive Grid - model.getRecord(selectedRecords )returns null in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to fetch all the selected records from the interactive grid in Oracle APEX by writing the below piece of code. I have also declared #myStaticIgId as the static Id of my report.

```
        var record, USER_NAME;
        var x = '';

        var l_role = $v("P2_ROLE");
        var l_justification = $v("P2_JUSTIFICATION");
        var l_date = $v("P2_DATE");

        //Identify the particular interactive grid
        var ig$     = apex.region("myStaticIgId").widget();

        //Fetch the model for the interactive grid
        var grid    = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");

        //Fetch the model for the interactive grid
        var model   = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;



        //Fetch selected records
        var selectedRecords = apex.region("myStaticIgId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").view$.grid("getSelectedRecords");
         alert(selectedRecords.length);

        //Loop through selected records 
        for (idx=0; idx < selectedRecords.length; idx++) {
            //Get the record
            record = model.getRecord(selectedRecords[idx][0]);

             alert(record);

            //Get the current value for USER_NAME
             USER_NAME  = model.getValue(record,"USER_NAME");
            //  USER_NAME  = 'Abha';

            alert('submit 2');


         }
```

The alert statement that I have written for returning the record value, returns NULL to me.

Can you please suggest, what needs to be done so as to get the proper record value in record variable.

Regards,
Abha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it working. the issue was the ordering of the primary key column. The primary key column should be the first column in the list after "APEX$ROW_SELECTOR" and "APEX$ROW_ACTION".

My column "ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER" with the primary key was not the first column while column "USER_NAME" was the first column in the REgions. Hence it was working for USER_NAME and not for "ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER". After changing the order of this column as first column, It worked.

[image]

Hope this also helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code (with some changes) here and works.

1 - Define the region ID of your Interactive Grid.
[image]

2 - Go to chrome -> open console (press F12) -> try this code:

```
var gridID = "orders";
var ig$ = apex.region(gridID).widget();
var grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
var model   = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;
var selectedRecords = grid.getSelectedRecords();

for (idx = 0; idx < selectedRecords.length; idx++) {
    record = model.getRecord(selectedRecords[idx][0]);
    console.log(record);
    console.log(model.getValue(record,"USER_NAME"));
}
```

- I tested this code in this page: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:8

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But I used exactly the same code as you have mentioned,but still I am getting the same error. The record value it is returning is coming out as NULL. Exact error is : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null". I have done this kind of coding earlier and it used to work. Not able to understand why it is not working now..

Comment: Also, when I try to print the - alert(selectedRecords) , it returns the correct selected record, but after that when  I call - 'record = model.getRecord(selectedRecords[idx][0]);' this statement and print the record's value, it gives me NULL value. So somewhere It is giving error while getting the record.

Comment: I am again lookin into this issue.. I have 2 columns in interactive grid- "User_NAME" & "ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER" . If I set USER_NAME as primary key, I get proper record value when i print "alert(record);". But I f I set Assignment_number as Primary key I get "NULL" for "alert(record);". I am not able to figure out why this happens. And actually I want only Assignment number as primary key not the username. Does somebody has any suggestion, how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having similar issue. Flag is "Selected List"(Yes/No). I am trying to change Flag value from "No" to "Yes" for selected Rows, However value is not getting changed.
I am using below code.

```
function changeFlag(){
var isVerified;
var ig$     = apex.region("New").widget();
var grid    = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
var model   = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;
var selectedRecords = apex.region("New").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").view$.grid("getSelectedRecords");
for (idx=0; idx < selectedRecords.length; idx++) {
    record = model.getRecord(selectedRecords[idx][0]);
 console.log(record);
    isVerified  = model.getValue(record,"FLAG");
    console.log(isVerified);
    if (isVerified === 'N') {
        model.setValue(record,"FLAG", 'Y');
    }  
}
}
```

Sample application is available in [this link](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/bsrk/r/demo81/home?session=705442417594700)
I am not understanding where i made issue.

Actual issue is Update the flag for bulk records using IG. I am trying to change the value to "Yes" and then will save the records. I am stuck because of this issue.